# IE Right-Click Save Target As .DWG File type Error

Tags: internet-explorer, right-click, save-as, dwg

**Background:** My web application allows users to upload images and files that are later available for download by presenting a  link that the user can Right-Click Save As.

**My issue:** In Internet Explorer when the user Right-click Save Target As and the file is a .DWG file there is an **error:**

> Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The
>   requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found

Is it possible to make IE save the file locally (or wherever the user browses to)?

Comment: Does it work if you try to download it with other browsers?

Comment: I have tested it with FF and Chrome and no issues. I get the file save window like I would expect.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE have you tested with?  Which web server is hosting the app/files? IIS? Are you serving things via HTTPS?

Comment: It has been tested in IE 8 and IE 10 both with the same result. It is running on a Windows Server and ColdFusion.

Comment: Are you serving it up as HTTPS? What are your Cache-control headers set to? (See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308 for where I'm headed with this :) )

Comment: It is not being served as HTTPS. I am not setting any rules for caching on the pages. I had read about if the page is set to no-cache that it will try and open the file or something. The page has the links is part of password protected section of the site.

Comment: If the user is selecting "Save Target As" they are already attempting to save it locally.  I am not sure I fully understand the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound when they select Save Target As they get a windows error message which I listed above. This keeps the user from saving any files of this type.

Comment: @Denoteone - *Yes*, I realize that.  I highly suspect `Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007` is on to something.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like it is to do with xml.
Check your content-type tags see if they include the .dwg format

Open cmd.exe and try the following command: `regsvr32 msxml3.dll`

I'm assuming you don't want your users having to run a cmd prompt command to dl the file. So yeah look at the xml of your web app.

Comment: I am assuming this would be run on the windows server hosting the site? The application itself is running in ColdFusion.

Comment: @Denoteone - No;  It would be run by the user.